# Confuse about css z-index

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

I have two layer,one is black overlay:

```
#overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

the other is my text container:

```
#wrap {
    z-index: 999
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    border:5px solid black;
    display:none;
    color:red;
}
```

I want let the overlay and the container show at the same time:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $('#overlay').add('#wrap').fadeIn();
})​​
```

but the text container is always under the overlay,although I have set the overlay `z-index` to `0` and set the container `z-index` to 999.

Demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RrL2G/7/)

finally I found I have to set the overlay `z-index` to `-1`, it would work.

Why I can not set the overlay's `z-index` more higher?Because its position is fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` is not applied to `#wrap` because it has flow positioning. A box must have at least `position: relative;` before `z-index` takes effect.

Also, your `z-index` value is missing its semicolon. Make it `z-index: 999;` and it works. My code is below:

```
#wrap {
    z-index: 999;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    border:5px solid black;
    background: #FFF;
    display:none;
    color:red;
    position: relative; }
```

Answer (score 0):

An element with static positioning(this is the default) is unaffected by the z-index property, change its positioning to relative